# Uri Scheme for Movie in the Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store app.  In the app I'm using the Groove SDK to query the Microsoft Store for movie titles.  I can get the movie I'm looking for along with all of it's meta data.  How can I launch the Windows Store app to show the user the same movie as available from Microsoft?

This has been very confusing.  I have a Surface with Windows 8.1. It comes with the Windows Store app, a Music app and a Video app.  The Video app says "xbox video." I've read that it has now changed to "Groove."  I've look for documentation on how to link content but have found nothing.

Comment: Here's the URL for the SDK. https://music.microsoft.com/Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Groove SDK APIs will return deep links to content. Launch this deep link using Windows API

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(myGrooveDeepLink));
```

Notice that you will have to add a "target=app" parameter to your uri to launch the app instead of the web site.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546675.aspx

Comment: It works but it's launching both the web browser and the Microsoft Store app.  How can I get it to launch the Microsoft Store app only?  Here's my URL:  "http://music.microsoft.com/track/michael-giacchino/jurassic-world-original-motion-picture-soundtrack/sunrise-oer-jurassic-world/1a1c2609-0100-11db-89ca-0019b92a3933?partnerID=com-customplay-windows-dev&action=buy&target=app"

Comment: Read the "App-to-app direct linking" section of the link I provided ;)